# Reg Exp: Multiple Words with Spaces (%20)

Tags: regex

I am trying to capture the keyword used to get to my website from a Google Ad. I have it mostly all working except I can't figure out how to get it to read multiple keywords.

---

Here is an example URL that would be clicked on:

```
http://www.example.com/?ccampaign=hydraulic_repair&keyword=hard%20chrome%20plating
```

Which shows up in the URL bar like this (no %20, just a space)

```
http://www.example.com/?ccampaign=hydraulic_repair&keyword=hard chrome plating
```

And in my JS the ALERT only alerts "hard" and not "hard chrome plating"

```
var URLkeyword = location.href.match(/keyword=([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)/)
alert(URLkeyword);
```

---

I have tried a number of variations with adding a " " (space), using \s, and adding in %20, but all this seemed to accomplish was ALERTING "h", or "hard".

Any suggestions for what I'm missing? Not so great with RegEx -_-

Comment: Console log `location.href`. What is it? Is the `Google Ad` related to your issue, seems like you are just trying to pull the data with JS.

Comment: It would be the URL I posted in my question above. I replaced the live site with example.com. Yes I am just trying to pull data from the URL with JS.

Comment: In the question you posted 2 URLs. What is it when logged `%20` or a space? (I don't use JS often, not sure if it auto decodes URLs). Depending on what it is please show the space or `%20` you used in your regex.

Comment: As I tried to explain. The first link is the one you would click on (Google Ad, which includes %20), when it takes you to my website the 2nd URL is the one that appears in the URL bar (%20 are gone and replaced with space). Is there a way to account for a space and %20 to cover both scenarios?

Comment: It depends on what browser you are in, some pretty print URL encodings. For example `fün` displayed in chrome is really, `f%C3%BCn`. Maybe what you want is https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern capturing the `keyword`'s value may be "anything followed by a parameter delimiter (`&`) or end of string (`$`)":

```
keyword=(.*?)(?:&|$)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/urE2pc/1

Comment: Thanks Dmitry!! This ALERTS "hard%20chrome%20plating", which I can work with :)

Comment: Used decodeURI(URLkeyword) to remove %20 if anyone reading this is wondering.

Comment: @chris85: I wouldn't recommend using `decodeURI(location.href)` before regex pattern match since it may spoil the match. For example, if unescaped `&` will appear in the decoded value, the regex in this answer will fail. Other regexes may also fail if the decoded value would reveal certain characters.

Comment: @DmitryEgorov - So you're saying `.*?` won't match `&` ?

Comment: @sln The `.*?` would stop at an `&` if the keyword contained that and was decoded. I hadn't thought of a `&` being url encoded.

Comment: @sln: I'm saying the regex would fail if `decodeURI(location.href)` were to return something like `...&keyword=mickey mouse &co`

Comment: Ok, I see, the `&` is being used as a parameter delimiter.